# truncated predictions for continuous proportion response variable using either beta regression or quasi-likelihood methods

Tags: regression, beta-distribution

I have tried two approaches for predicting a continuous proportion response variable in both SAS (proc glimmix) and R (glmx): beta regression and a quasi-likelihood approach.  I have tried both logit and loglog link functions.  While overall the plot of predicted vs observed looks good, a closer examination of predictions at the low end shows that predictions are truncated at ~ 0.03 while observed data extend down to zero.  The data set is skewed, with many observations near zero.  I have tried implementing the bias correction options in R and it helped slightly but the lower threshold still exists.  Is there something else I should be trying?